# Unable to rollback BMT EJB UserTransaction in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, jdbc, ejb

My application is using Struts2, EJB3 session Stateless bean, JDBC, MYSQL.
I am unable to rollback complete transaction on an exception. 
I have used BMT, User Transaction in EJB3 Statemless bean and used JDBC and database is MYSQL.
I am inserting three records, one in parent table, two records in the child.
I mock an exception after inserting in Parent and one Child, the usertransaction is able to roll back from a child but not from a parent. Please advise

Please find code below
EJB

```
@Stateless
@Remote
@RemoteBinding(jndiBinding = AppConstants.JNDI_BINDING_CTRADE)
@TransactionManagement(value=TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
public class CManager implements CManagement {


        @Override
        public void saveDetails(String sessionId) {
            try {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 userTransaction.begin();
                CInterface cInterface = createCInstance(sessionId, true);
                cInterface.saveDetails3(sessionId);
                cInterface.saveDetails2(sessionId);
                String st=null;
                if(st.equals("test")); // So fake a null pointer
                cInterface.saveDetails1(sessionId);             
                 userTransaction.commit();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                 try {
                    userTransaction.rollback();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (SecurityException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (SystemException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }




}
```

DAO

```
    @Override
    public void saveDetails3(String sessionId) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
        PreparedStatement pstm2 = null;
        PreparedStatement pstm3 = null;

        Connection connection = null;
        Integer id =0, id2 =0,id3 =0;
        String query1= "Insert into transaction(transactionId,outputProductId) values ('ST8' , '108')";

        try {
            connection = connectionManager.getConnection();
            pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(query1,
                    Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
            pstmt.execute();
            ResultSet rs = pstmt.getGeneratedKeys();
            while (rs.next()) {
                id = rs.getInt(1);
            }
            System.out.println("ST id" + id);



        } catch (SQLException se) {
            LOGGER.error(se.getMessage(), se);
            throw se;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            throw e;
        } finally {
            /* Closing Connection Objects */
            if (connection != null) {
                try {
                    connection.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
                    throw e;
                }
            }
        }

    }

@Override
    public void saveDetails1(String sessionId) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
        PreparedStatement pstm2 = null;
        PreparedStatement pstm3 = null;

        Connection connection = null;
        Integer id =0, id2 =0,id3 =0;
        String query1= "Insert into child(transactionId , inputproductId ,outputproductId ,ratio) values ('ST8' , 'I08' ,'O01','5');";

        try {
            connection = connectionManager.getConnection();
            pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(query1,
                    Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
            pstmt.execute();
            ResultSet rs = pstmt.getGeneratedKeys();
            while (rs.next()) {
                id = rs.getInt(1);
            }
            System.out.println(" id1" + id);



        } catch (SQLException se) {
            LOGGER.error(se.getMessage(), se);
            throw se;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            throw e;
        } finally {
            /* Closing Connection Objects */
            if (connection != null) {
                try {
                    connection.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
                    throw e;
                }
            }
        }       
    }

    @Override
    public void saveDetails2(String sessionId) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
        PreparedStatement pstm2 = null;
        PreparedStatement pstm3 = null;

        Connection connection = null;
        Integer id =0, id2 =0,id3 =0;
        String query1= "Insert into child(transactionId , inputproductId ,outputproductId ,ratio) values ('ST8' , 'I07' ,'O02','5');";

        try {
            connection = connectionManager.getConnection();
            pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(query1,
                    Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
            pstmt.execute();
            ResultSet rs = pstmt.getGeneratedKeys();
            while (rs.next()) {
                id = rs.getInt(1);
            }
            System.out.println(" id2 " + id);



        } catch (SQLException se) {
            LOGGER.error(se.getMessage(), se);
            throw se;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            throw e;
        } finally {
            /* Closing Connection Objects */
            if (connection != null) {
                try {
                    connection.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
                    throw e;
                }
            }
        }       
    }
```

Here the transaction is partially rollbacked

Comment: In each of your saveDetails method, you create get a new connection to the database. The [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#close--) says `It is strongly recommended that an application explicitly commits or rolls back an active transaction prior to calling the close method. If the close method is called and there is an active transaction, the results are implementation-defined`. So it could be that the changes in the first 2 method calls are already commited before the exception occurs. Perhaps better using the same connection for all 3 method calls.

Comment: hi @Lini, here we are using BMT EJB usertransaction.